# property file from jar spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jar

I have a following jar that I want to include in my spring boot app

[image: jar]

how we can load these properties file in project where we are going to include this jar file ? and should not conflict with applicaiton.property of current project? any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple property files with the same name if you want to load them without any issues.

There are many ways to load property file as [explained here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). With `PropertySource`, you can do it as shown below

`@PropertySource( value = { "classpath:application.properties","classpath:bootstrap.properties"})`

Comment: My properties files are came in jar file which contain those properties that is required by classes, in jar. so these properties are not on class path .. by default

Comment: If you are adding your test client jar as a dependency, those files will be available automatically in classpath.